# Meaning of "on" in the expression "operation on a set $A$"

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

What is the meaning of "on" in the expression "operation **on** a set $A$"?

Does it mean that:

- at least one of the operands is in $A$;
- all the operands are in $A$; or
- all the operands are in $A$ and the codomain is $A$?

(There are some similar questions, but they are specific to *binary* operations. As languages are not completely logical, "binary" may imply more restrictions than just "the number of operands is two")

Comment: For example I would consider the tensor product on modules as an operation on that module even though the codomain can be different from the initial module.  So the last option shouldn't be the meaning. I don't think I would consider scalar multiplication as an operation on the vector space, so I think I would go with the second option.

Comment: In the end it depends on the context, that phrase is pretty freely used and I don't think there is much point in exactly exactly defining what's meant. If you read it somewhere it should be clear from the context what's meant.

Comment: Typically means its a relation on $A$, i.e. $A$ is the domain. An operation on the integers might map it to $\{0,1\}$ for whether its even or odd. It might map it to its binary representation. It's especially important in Group Theory where you have a binary operatin mapping A to itself.

Comment: It may also mean that all elements of A contribute to the result. The operator "order" for example would map the number of  elements in A to some non-negative integer (or infinity). Or: for a partially ordered set the Hasse diagrams are graphs that operate on the set. Most often is will mean that the output is only defined for members of A, but also for all members of A.